# Ionic for Windows - No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to run my ionic project on Windows device.
For that I have installed Visual Studio 2015 in my Windows 10 System.

When I create a new Cordova Project on Visual Studio 2015 and built it for WindowsPhone Device, one exception is displayed

```
No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target
```

I have also change value in config.xml from

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
```

to

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

Furthermore, I have set variable "VCTargetsPath" to path "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120", where my MSBuild is located.

But I still get the below error.

[image]

Please help me find what I have missed. Do we need to specify the project's sln somewhere?